# Executing up() method

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have `up` method in a migration file `2016_07_08_121013_drop_templates_table.php`

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::drop('templates');
}
```

I have to recreate templates table in `down()` method. Is there a way I don't have to repeat myself? Something like executing `up`method from other migration that create template table?

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

```
private function createTable(){
    Schema::create('table', function( ....
    //the table schema
    );
}
```

and then call it on your `up` or `down` method like this:

```
$this->createTable();
```

you can make that method public and then call it to another file if that's what you're looking for